# How To Save PassportToken on user login laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, laravel-5.3

i make API by laravel passport 
i wanna save passport token in cookies when login is successful 
i tried to make this in home controller but it always generate different key

Comment: Why different laravel versions as tags? Why do you make cookie twice? What is going wrong, cookie generation or a token?

Comment: ignor that  smiple equation how to make cookie on login

Comment: What is going wrong in this code? Explain, please.

Comment: there is no wrong i dont know how to make cookie on login

Comment: Please ask a direct question, this is not a forum for advice. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Include what you are trying to do, what you have tried, and what happened instead of what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `withCookie` method of a Response object?

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

...

$UserToken = Auth::user()->createToken('MyApp')->accessToken;
$view = view('Ades Admin.DashBoard');
$response = new Response($view);

return $response->withCookie(cookie('valid', $UserToken, 10));
```